# What exactly happened to Ronnie in The Flash?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

So I finished watching the first season of *The Flash* on Netflix and recently started watching the second season. And of course, in all the chaos and world-saving that was going on in the first season's finale (and second season premiere), Dr. Stein and Ronnie combine to form Firestorm and fly into the middle of the singularity to save Barry. When the singularity is successfully closed (or whatnot) and all is safe, Dr. Stein falls - by himself, separated from Ronnie somehow. So we assume that Ronnie died, but it seems that his body just... vanished or something. What exactly happened that Dr. Stein survived, but Ronnie didn't? (*And* there was no body?) Is the presumption that somehow they separated, but Ronnie got sucked through the singularity, while Dr. Stein didn't? (I mean, Firestorm had to have separated back into two different individuals for Dr. Stein to have gotten his own body back, right?)

Edit: In case it wasn't clear, the question isn't about whether or not Ronnie died - Ronnie is definitively dead. However, it was a very... odd... death, and I was wondering if anybody had an explanation for *exactly* how the singularity killed Ronnie but not Dr. Stein, among other weirdnesses of the death, like Firestorm somehow managing to separate back into two different people before the death (when it didn't seem like there would be an opportunity for that to happen), and then Ronnie's body not being present and accounted for at the end of the ordeal. (As far as I could tell, anyway - at the very least, I don't think they show a body...) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the explanation given in season 2. Ronnie died via heroic sacrifice to close up the singularity. Or atleast the scoobies and production currently consider him killed in action. Much like Professor Stein,  he would have gone nuclear alone. And much like Stein, he could have survived by finding someone to bond with, wherever he ended up. Comic book heroes don't stay dead. See Barry, Zoom, Eobard, Heatwave, Arrow, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I got that he died - the question is related to specifics of how it happened. I.e. *How* exactly did this singularity kill Ronnie so that (a) he separated from Dr. Stein mid-air, (b) Dr. Stein survived and he didn't, and (c) his body kinda just... poofed? Was there any explanation given to *how* he died (beyond just the general "it was related in some way to being in the singularity") that would answer any of the peculiarities of the death? Thanks!

Comment: Firestorm expended to much energy, so be depowered, separated. Ronnie got sucked into the singularity while Stein got thrown out. No further details given to leave the possibility of a return open.

Comment: The point being that you understood all the information given to us in the show.

Comment: You actually just provided a bit more info that I didn't know - and that you didn't put in your answer. If you can source it, I'd actually encourage you to add it to your answer! :)

Comment: This is what I recall, as well. It might be covered better in a later episode flashback?